# How to store integer value into an array in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My mutableArray is

```
NSDictionary *dict;
self.dayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[xmlParseArray count]];
for(dict in xmlParseArray)
    if([dict objectForKey:@"day"])
    [self.dayArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"day"]];

NSLog(@"dayArray is : %@",dayArray);
dayArray print : 10,15,26,28....
```

I want to convert these value into integer format and store it another array. For this I am doing this:

```
int currentNumber;
for(int i=0; i<[dayArray count]; i++)
{
    currentNumber = [((NSNumber*)[dayArray objectAtIndex:i]) intValue];

}
NSLog(@"currentNumber is : %d",currentNumber);
```

currentNumber print 10,15,26,28 but I want to store it into array having integer format. These are day and I want to show these day into calendar with highlighted red color

Comment: you have 14 questions with answers, but you accepted none. Why?

Comment: I agree with vikingosegundo, accept answers assuming you want more help.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't just pass dayArrayDirectly? It is already have NSNumber Objects into it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
[dictionaryArray setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"ANumberValue"];
```